# Output files for mappers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have map-reduce job that just uses the mapper. Right now when I run the job I have these part-m-***** files that club the output of different mappers. If I want one part-m-***** file for one mapper, how do I do that. Is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [getmerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge)? It is usually used to combine the part* files into a single file.

Comment: I think you dint get my question. My question is not to combine the all the part files into a single file. My question is to not generate those multiple files itself. My question is how do I control the generation of part-m-* files. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "club the output of different mappers". Are you saying you're getting more part files than the number of mappers you're running?

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean here - in what way do you want to control the output?

Comment: I want to control the output in a way that it contains only one file. But I guess then I have to use only one mapper which defeats the whole purpose of map-reduce. Basically what I was trying to do was to track the splits. So that I can use the splits to calculate the line numbers. Anyways what I was trying to do was not good. Thank you for your reply

Comment: That's what the reduce step is for.